# For Geany on Windows 11, how can I create a "build and run" command?

Tags: geany, geany-plugin

In Geany, I need to build the program first and then run it.

I was wondering if there is one button for build and run--as in codeblocks, for example--it would be nice. I've tried so many different things, but nothing seems to work. I've tried to add this command, but as I stated it didn't work: `g++ -Wall -o "%e" "%f" && "./%e"`

Here are the default build commands:

[image: An image of my build commands, which are the default ones]

I've tried the proposed solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777590/how-to-config-geany-to-build-and-execute-at-the-same-time), but they didn't work.

Is there a way to have a button do "build and run" in the Geany IDE?